# Javascript code needed of explination (recursion example)

Tags: javascript

My main problem is that I cant seem to understand how to solve the problem on paper let alone understand the code, or write my own. Heres the excerpt from Eloquent JavaScript, a book I am reading.

Consider this puzzle: By starting from the number 1 and repeatedly either adding 5 or multiplying by 3, an infinite amount of new numbers can be produced. How would you write a function that, given a number, tries to find a sequence of additions and multiplications that produce that number?

¶ For example, the number 13 could be reached by first multiplying 1 by 3, and then adding 5 twice. The number 15 can not be reached at all.

¶ Here is the solution:

```
 function findSequence(goal) {
   function find(start, history) {
     if (start == goal)
      return history;
     else if (start > goal)
       return null;
     else
       return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
              find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
   }
   return find(1, "1");
 }

 print(findSequence(24));
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @musefan i think he wants to explain the code

Comment: @Harikrishnan: yeah... that isn't going to happen

Comment: Why not? This is as much a programming question as any other.

Comment: @ThaMe90: There isn't technically any question at all, it's just an order. Also, this kind of thing doesn't fit in with the SO rules, mainly because it is too specific. Then we have to consider why the OP's book doesn't already explain what it does, pretty useless book IMO

Comment: IMO the question isn't too specific, as the example just demonstrates recursion

Comment: It's a way of finding an arithmetical expression composed of just 3 and 5 and + and *. This expression will evaluate to the number that is given as argument(the argument called `goal`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findSequence(goal) {

   // define a function that has a 'start' number (current total),
   // and a string that is the history of what we've done so far
   // (and note that for this function, the 'goal' parameter above is in scope).
   function find(start, history) {
     // if we've reached the goal, return the string that says how we got there
     if (start == goal)
      return history;
     // if we've overshot, return null
     else if (start > goal)
       return null;
     else
       // call this same function (recursion) with two different possibile ways of
       // getting closer to the goal - one adding 5 and one multiplying by 3...
       // the or ('||') operator will return the first of the two that is not null
       return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
              find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
   }
   // start at 1
   return find(1, "1");
 }
```

Comment: Thank You sje397. I will study your comments.

Comment: So you think this is an acceptable question then? Not too specific perhaps? Do you think "explain findSequence function from Eloquent JavaScript book" is a common search term?

Comment: @musefan Yeah it's ok...could use the word 'recursion' in the question title.

Comment: It may use recursion, but this is a terrible example of it. If someone wanted to understand recursion this is not the most friendly code to be using for explanation. I just really don't think SO is the place to ask "explain my code that already works" type questions

Comment: I dont want to let any code go by not understood. I tried to find my own solution and it was nothing like this one. The author attempts to explain the code but does so in rather technical terms, in a matter of speaking. So I wanted a second explanation of the code. One from a peer, that I may understand this. Sorry if I broke any rules.